# Xcode 6 - Save for iOS App Store Deployment requires access to the development team?

Tags: ios, deployment, export, xcode6

I need to export application for App Store distribution for client.
Client does not agree to give me access to his development team.
In previous Xcode version it was not a problem: client was exporting his Appstore certificate and provisioning profile, I used it to sign an app and send back to him.

But in **Xcode 6, Organizer -> Archives -> Export...  there is no option to select certificate anymore. I must select team first.**

[image]

What to do if I have no access to the team's portal? How can I export app for AppStore for client who does not agree to give an access to his development team?

**Edit:** I have proper AppStore cert and provisioning profile from the client.

The question is:
Is making archive enough (signed with cert and profile provided)? If I just send prepared archive to them, will they be able to use it?

Previosuly, when I exported ipa, it had to be reassigned again.

Comment: It turned out to be enough to send `xcarchive` package. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help:

Using xcodebuild To Export a .ipa from an Archive
[Link](http://www.thecave.com/2014/09/16/using-xcodebuild-to-export-a-ipa-from-an-archive/)

> >
>   xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath $projectname.xcarchive -exportPath $projectname -exportFormat ipa -exportProvisioningProfile “Provisioning Profile Name”

Answer (score 0):

If you needed just .ipa file, you can use Distribution Provision Profile. Otherwise, if you just want to use Developer Provision Profile, please check Team ID firstly. When keychain's **Iphone Developer: Thar Htet(Team ID)** was not same by **Team ID that is created IOS App IDs**, it will see to be signed with cert and profile provided.